# Akka.NET Persistence with SQL Server not working

Tags: sql-server, akka.net

I've been trying to implement the simple example [here](https://petabridge.com/blog/intro-to-persistent-actors/).

I've created the required tables in SQL Server as described in the GitHub repository and the HOCON configuration. The application runs without errors but nothing gets persisted. I did see an early discussion where someone else had the same problem and the solution was supposedly to call SqlServerPersistence.Init() function, with a note that this would soon be no longer required. And in fact the method no longer exists.

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var actorSystem = ActorSystem.Create("PersistenceActorSystem"))
            {
                SqlServerPersistence persistence = SqlServerPersistence.Get(actorSystem);

                var actor = actorSystem.ActorOf(Props.Create<ParentActor>(), "ParentActor");

                actorSystem.WhenTerminated.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Actor system shutdown...");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}


public class ParentActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public ParentActor()
    {
        var actor = Context.ActorOf(Props.Create<PersistentChildActor>(), "PersistentChildActor");

        actor.Tell("Message 1");
        actor.Tell("Message 2");
        actor.Tell(new PersistentChildActor.GetMessages());

        Receive<IReadOnlyList<string>>(messages =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received messages...");

            foreach (var message in messages)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }

            Context.System.Terminate();
        });
    }
}


public class PersistentChildActor : ReceivePersistentActor
{
    public class GetMessages {}

    private List<string> _messages = new List<string>(); 

    public override string PersistenceId
    {
        get
        {
            return "HardCoded";
        }
    }

    public PersistentChildActor()
    {
        // recover
        Recover<string>(message => _messages.Add(message));

        // commands
        Command<string>(message => Persist(message, s =>
        {
            _messages.Add(message); //add msg to in-memory event store after persisting
        }));
        Command<GetMessages>(get =>
        {
            IReadOnlyList<string> messages = new List<string>(_messages);
            Sender.Tell(messages);
        });
    }
}
```

I'm using Akka 1.0.8 with Persistence 1.0.8.25 and Persistence.SqlServer 1.0.6.3.

Hocon config

```
    akka {
      akka.persistence{

          journal {
              plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.sql-server"
              sql-server {

                  class = "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal, Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"

                  connection-string = "Data Source=USER-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AkkaPersistenceDemo;Integrated Security=True;"

                  schema-name = dbo

                  auto-initialize = on
              }
          }

          snapshot-store {
              plugin = "akka.persistence.snapshot-store.sql-server"
              sql-server {

                  class = "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotStore, Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"

                  connection-string = "Data Source=USER-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AkkaPersistenceDemo;Integrated Security=True;"

                  schema-name = dbo

                  auto-initialize = on
              }
          }
      }          
    }
```

Comment: Could you add your current Hocon config? You probably have an error in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
akka {
    akka.persistence{
```

To

```
akka {
    persistence{
```

It seems your persistence settings are not applied, and journal defaults to inmem

Comment: Thanks @andrey.leskov. It's now working. I removed the outer akka element in my case, as I've nothing else in the HOCON. But I also tried nesting persistence inside akka as you suggested, which also works. I also had to update my journal table with an extra column that's been added since I first tried it.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this as well. I fixed it by setting the journal plugin in the HOCON config.

```
journal {
  plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.sql-server"
    sql-server {

        # qualified type name of the SQL Server persistence journal actor
        class = "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal, Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"

        # dispatcher used to drive journal actor
        plugin-dispatcher = "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"
```

If you inspect your Actor instance's **Journal** property before making this change you would notice that it is set to the in memory journal. That is why you don't see it persisted.

Comment: My bad, I was using Persistence 1.0.6.17-beta in my code which does work. Persistence (and Persistence.Sql.Common) version 1.0.8.25 throws an NullReferenceException while attempting to CreateNewActorInstance(0.

Comment: I set the journal plugin but it made no difference in my case. The Journal property was still showing the in memory journal.

Comment: You saved my day. It works with version (1.1.1.7-beta)

Answer (score 0):

There is no SqlServer provider for Akka 1.0.8 right now. You could build it from sources or download a nuget package from Akka nightly builds (https://www.myget.org/F/akkadotnet/api/v2)